# Sort array of arrays into groups based on group number

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, grouping, nested-lists

I have an array of arrays. I am trying to split them up into 4 groups of 3 each. Here is the code...

```
random.shuffle(top_twelve_players_info)
top_twelve_players_info_copy = top_twelve_players_info[:]

group_1 = []
group_2 = []
group_3 = []
group_4 = []

for i in range(3):
    group_1.append(top_twelve_players_info_copy[i])
    top_twelve_players_info_copy.remove(top_twelve_players_info_copy[i])
print(f"Group 1: {group_1}")

for i in range(3):
    group_2.append(top_twelve_players_info_copy[i])
    top_twelve_players_info_copy.remove(top_twelve_players_info_copy[i])
print(f"Group 2: {group_2}")

for i in range(3):
    group_3.append(top_twelve_players_info_copy[i])
    top_twelve_players_info_copy.remove(top_twelve_players_info_copy[i])
print(f"Group 3: {group_3}")

# print(top_twelve_players_info_copy)

for i in range(3):
    group_4.append(top_twelve_players_info_copy[i])
    # top_twelve_players_info_copy.remove(top_twelve_players_info_copy[i])
print(f"Group 4: {group_4}")
```

Currently, the `top_twelve_players_info` looks like

```
[
    ['Krombopulos Michael', 10, 3],
    ['Scary Terry', 2, 11],
    ['Jerry Smith', 7, 6],
    ['Blim Blam ', 11, 2],
    ['Summer Smith', 1, 12],
    ['Tophat Jones', 5, 8],
    ['Beth Smith', 6, 7],
    ['Abradolf Lincler', 4, 9],
    ['Alan Rails', 12, 1],
    ['Morty Smith', 3, 10],
    ['Rick Sanchez', 9, 4],
    ['Xenon Bloom', 3, 10]
]
```

I was looking for a more efficient implementation instead of repeating the `for` loops and somehow even make the `group_1` or `group_2` variables depending on the iteration number. Also, for some reason, with the current implementation, I get the error "list index out of range" only when making the 4th group. So I had to comment the remove line out. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you are mutating the list (removing items from it) while trying to loop through it by index (so index 2 is no longer there by the time your range loop gets to that value in your last for loop).

You can simplify the approach by just slicing the randomly shuffled list using a range loop with steps equivalent to the size of the groups you want to output. Following is an approach that puts the resulting groups in a single list and then prints the output similar to your example.

```
import random

top_twelve_players_info = [['Krombopulos Michael', 10, 3], ['Scary Terry', 2, 11], ['Jerry Smith', 7, 6], ['Blim Blam ', 11, 2], ['Summer Smith', 1, 12], ['Tophat Jones', 5, 8], ['Beth Smith', 6, 7], ['Abradolf Lincler', 4, 9], ['Alan Rails', 12, 1], ['Morty Smith', 3, 10], ['Rick Sanchez', 9, 4], ['Xenon Bloom', 3, 10]]

random.shuffle(top_twelve_players_info)
groups = [top_twelve_players_info[i:i+3] for i in range(0, 12, 3)]

for i, group in enumerate(groups):
    print(f'Group {i + 1}: {group}')

# EXAMPLE OUTPUT (differs based on random shuffle results)
# Group 1: [['Beth Smith', 6, 7], ['Scary Terry', 2, 11], ['Krombopulos Michael', 10, 3]]
# Group 2: [['Xenon Bloom', 3, 10], ['Rick Sanchez', 9, 4], ['Tophat Jones', 5, 8]]
# Group 3: [['Morty Smith', 3, 10], ['Abradolf Lincler', 4, 9], ['Jerry Smith', 7, 6]]
# Group 4: [['Summer Smith', 1, 12], ['Alan Rails', 12, 1], ['Blim Blam ', 11, 2]]
```

Or if you really need each group assigned to its own variable:

```
[group_1, group_2, group_3, group_4] = [top_twelve_players_info[i:i+3] for i in range(0, 12, 3)]

print(f'Group 1: {group_1}')
print(f'Group 2: {group_2}')
print(f'Group 3: {group_3}')
print(f'Group 4: {group_4}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Sticking to python standard library (instead of `pandas` which would provide much more elegant solution) you should probably go like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
groups = defaultdict(list)

players_cnt = 0
for group_no in range(4):
    for player_cnt in range(3):
        selected_player = top_twelve_players_info_copy[players_cnt]
        groups[group_no].append(selected_player)  # here defaultdict makes it more elegant - we do not need to check if group_no is a key in groups
```

Now, if you really need to you can extract groups to separate variables (but I would strongly suggest keeping it in the dictionary keyed by the group number):

```
group_1 = groups[1]  # ...etc.
```

Comment: Would that make sure I do not have duplicates in the groups? Like 'Harry' being in Group 1 and 2 as well? That's why I had used the 'remove' function

Comment: As long as the list contains only unique names there will not be any duplicates in the groups.